# Flask RESTful POST JSON fails

Tags: python, json, rest, curl, flask

I have a problem posting JSON via curl from cmd (Windows7) to Flask RESTful.
This is what I post:

```
curl.exe -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST \
 -d '{"Hello":"Karl"}' http://example.net:5000/
```

It results in a bad request, also I don't know how to debug this, normally I would print out information to console, but this doesn't work. How do you debug wsgi apps? Seems like a hopeless task...

This is my simple test app as seen on the net:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.ext.restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Test(Resource):
    def post(self):
        #printing request.data works
        json_data = request.get_json(force=True) # this issues Bad request
        # request.json also does not work
        return {}

api.add_resource(Test, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-d '{"Hello":"Karl"}'` doesn't work from windows as its surrounded by single quotes. Use double quotes around and it will work for you.

```
-d "{\"Hello\":\"Karl\"}"
```

Comment: thank you! been expecting the problem to be god knows where, instead of using goodle with "curl json windows". again thx

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that you need to escape regardless of OS - and regardless if you have double quotes around the request data - I saw this post and didn't think it was the answer to my issue because I had double quotes around the request data and single quotes inside:

This won't work:

```
-d "{'Hello': 'Karl'}"
```

This will:

```
-d "{\"Hello\":\"Karl\"}"
```

Again, you need to escape the quotes regardless of OS (I'm on Mac) and regardless of whether you have single or double quotes

And thanks [Sabuj Hassan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2953344/sabuj-hassan) for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

To add-on to the previous two answers, you do not **need** to escape the quotes across all OS's, following this syntax will work just fine on Mac/Linux:

```
-d '{"Hello":"Karl"}'
```